# What's special about the $T-V = H- 2V =2 T- H$, which the least action principle extremizes?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

My question is simple.

1. In the classical mechanics, we know the least action principle does the variation on the action
   $$
   S = \int (T-V) dt ,
   $$
   where $T$ is the kinetic term and $V$ is the potential term, to give the classical equations of motion.

So why the least action principle extremizes (minimizes or maxmizes) this quantity

$$T-V = H- 2V = E-2V =2 T- H = 2T-E?$$
Here I also denote $H$ as Hamiltonian. And $E$ as the energy of the system. In this regard, the $E$ is conserved, but not extremized. But $$E-2V =2T-E$$ is extremized!

2. For example, if we write down the $(T-V)$ for a free falling object under constant gravitational acceleration $g$, we have
   $$T-V = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{y}^2 - m g y = E -2 m g y =  m \dot{y}^2 -E$$
   with $E=\frac{1}{2} m \dot{y}^2 + m g y$ is conserved.
3. 

### What is the physical significance of this $T-V$?

(Provide good physical or math reasons.)

I know how to derive equations of motion. I am asking a transparent way to understand why $T-V$ is in extremization.

I suppose the extremization may minimizes or maximizes the action. (Not necessarily minimization, correct?) Do we have both examples of

- The equations of motion **minimize** the action?
- The equations of motion **maximize** the action?

Comment: If you would like the question to be re-opened, it would help to explain how it differs from the linked question.  In particular, $T-V$ is special precisely *because*, when extremized, it yields the correct equations of motion.  The answers to the linked question explain in detail why this is.  What else are you looking for?

Comment: I am asking a physical understanding of $T-V$. Just like the energy $E=T+V$ is conserved. What is special about $T-V$? I know equations of motion even in the level of classical or quantum field theory. I am not asking people to explain the equations of motion to me

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86008/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/585504/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123448/discussion-on-question-by-annie-marie-heart-whats-special-about-the-t-v-h-2).

Comment: I think the above discussions just show that none of us know why $ −$ is the action to extremize. No good intuitions.